# Security Vulnerability springfox-swagger2-3.0.0.jar

Tags: security, dependencies

I am working on one project and we are using tool Whitesource for our project.
The system Whitesource tells me usually that I need to update some dependency. Now it just says
Whitesource shows a problem **Security Vulnerability** with the message:

```
An issue was found in io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui. This vulnerability can lead to �Log injection�- whereas untrusted data gets written into log files/entries. It allows attackers to forge log entries or inject malicious content into the logs.
```

pom.xml

> ```
>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
>     <artifactId>springfox-swagger-common</artifactId>
>     <version>3.0.0</version>
>   </dependency>
>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
>     <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
>     <version>3.0.0</version>
>     <scope>compile</scope>
>   </dependency>
> ```

Please help me solve the problem or tell me where to start solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SpringFox https://github.com/springfox/springfox is not maintained for last 2 years. Applications currently leveraging SpringFox should migrate to [SpringDoc](https://springdoc.org/#Introduction).
[SprinDoc GitHub repo](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi) and [here is migration guide](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is currently no fix available from Springfox.
A little explanation: With this security issue, an attacker could write untrustworthy data in the log files and thus falsify log entries or inject malicious content into the logs.